# Call function in variable object using onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

Okay so here is my problem my javascript is so,

```
var example = {
    meep: function() {
            alert("This alert or function does not happen using onclick D:");
    }
}
```

Looks fine right? Okay so now when I do this,

```
<button onclick="example.meep()"></button>
```

It does not work and returns "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"
I can also do the function "example.meep()" in console and it works. I've tried it with and without ending parentheses.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n5uacjk2/ So what are you doing that is different?

Comment: Code is correct, problem will be on different place.

Comment: Is `example` defined in the global scope? Variables accessed in `onXXX` attributes have to be global.

Comment: May be wrapping the code in window.load event might help you

Comment: @rsakhale That's not necessary. You can't click the button until after the DOM is loaded.

Comment: What you've written should work, there's no way for us to tell why it's not working for you. You need to provide a fiddle that demonstrates the problem, or a link to your site so we can see what you're doing differently.

Comment: @Barmar The link to the game thing im working on is http://moreoverless.com/untitled/ The actual function is "cookie.reset()" as well as the other cookie functions. It only works in console. The buttons i'm using are in the center as the bottom of the wall of text. They are very obvious.

Comment: I changed it to `onclick="console.log(cookie); cookie.write()"`, and it's logging `game=1,1,20`. I don't know where that's coming from.

Comment: Try changing `var cookie` to `var mycookie`, and using `mycookie.write()` and `mycookie.reset()`. I wonder if there's a variable conflict somewhere that's causing this.

Comment: @Barmar OMG thank so you much. The library I was using also had a variable that used "cookie".

Comment: I saw that, but I'm not sure how it could conflict, since it's a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try attaching the example to the window. Change

```
var example = {
  ...
```

to

```
window.example = {
  ...
```

Comment: Um, if the variable `example` was not in scope, it would be a different error.

Comment: I suppose, the variable would be available in global scope

Comment: Maybe he has a different `example` variable in global scope, and it doesn't have a `meep` property.

Comment: @Barmar agreed! seems like the only plausible conclusion. Although OP says 'I can also do the function "example.meep()" in console and it works'